# get listBox selected indices returns empty array

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listbox

I have a ListBox with multiple selection mode

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListInspcteurs" runat="server" 
     CssClass="chzn-select liste ecr1" SelectionMode="Multiple">
</asp:ListBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ForeColor="Red"  
     id="RequiredFieldValidator8" ValidationGroup="Group1"
     controltovalidate="ListInspcteurs" errormessage="veuillez choisir au moins un inspecteur" />
```

The code behind to get back the selected items  :

```
ListBox list1 = (ListBox)PanelAffectation.FindControl("ListInspcteurs");
int[] indicesInspecteurs = list1.GetSelectedIndices();

List<int> idInspecteurs = new List<int>() ;

foreach (int i in indicesInspecteurs)
{
    int id = int.Parse(ListInspcteurs.Items[i].Value);
    idInspecteurs.Add(id);
}
```

When I debug `indicesInspecteurs` is null

I don't know what is going wrong, given that I have already used the same code with another list and it's working correctly

Comment: Do you have an initialization of the listbox somewhere in Page_Load which is executed again on the postback?

Comment: I think you should fill your list through an asp:ListItem or in the Page_Load like @smirnov said.

Comment: Now I Know where the problem come from , In my load method I call a function which makes all the controls enabled = false and for listbox ( enabled = false , but it works as it is not enabled so nothing was  noticed ; I don't know how enable false works for listbox ;